# Low FPS when naming application explorer.exe

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, windows-10

I have an Unity application let's call it X it usually runs at about 60 FPS. But when I rename the executable to Explorer (the same as Windows Explorer) my FPS drops to 7-8.

This is a screenshot from the profiler when the app is named X when the FPS is about 60:
[image]

This is another screenshot from the profiler with the same app but named explorer.exe when the FPS is about 8:
[image]

This is a screenshot of the GPU usage when named X.exe:
[image]

The same app named explorer.exe:
[image]

I'm can and will rename the app to something else, **but I'd like to know what causes this and how I can figure this out on my own**.

Things I've tried:

- Disabling my AV which is windows defender and restarting with no effect.
- Trying to reproduce it on a colleagues PC, with no success.

This makes me things that it might be specific to my machine and that maybe some process is trying to make some API calls on the other Explorer.exe and somehow affects my app.

In case it's relevant

- I'm using Unity 2019.3.5f1
- It's happening in the built app both debug and release

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
System Model:              Alienware 17 R4
System Type:               x64-based PC
```

Comment: Just .. then name it something else? :D Anyway that WaitingForTargetFPS thing is only happening in the UnityEditor itself and won't matter in a built app .. the great thing about finding running tasks in Windows scripts is: It's done by the task/program name so .... yes possible that anything is confusing your app with the explorer and trying to smuggle in some requests ^^

Comment: @derHugo I will rename, but still wanna figure out what and why it happens. This is me profiling the build app, it's not running in editor. Also I'm still trying to properly understand why WaitingForTargetFPS does so my Unity knowledge is quite limited when it comes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disappointingly the issue was cause by the fact the my windows was using the CPU graphics card instead of the dedicated one when the app was named explorer.exe.

To change this, I had to:

1. Go to  `Settings > System > Display > Graphics Settings`.
2. Browse and pick my app.
3. Select my app from the list.
4. Select `Options`.
5. Select `High performance`.
6. Select `Save`.

[Original source](https://www.howtogeek.com/351522/how-to-choose-which-gpu-a-game-uses-on-windows-10/)

This made my app use dedicated GPU instead of the integrated one.

Comment: Good to know that your driver seems to bind GPU performance settings on process name ;)